# How to split code into tokens using php?

Tags: php, split, tokenize

I have code that look like this in a string:

```
$code = "<html>
<body>
(if(foo == 10 || (foo == 20 && bar == 30))
    (foo(something)foo)
)if)
</body>
</html>";
```

How can I split the string to get in result:

```
array(
 "<html>\n<body>",
 "(if(",
 "foo == 10 || (foo == 20 && bar == 30))"
 "    ",
 "(foo(",
 "something",
 ")foo)",
 ")if)",
 "</body>\n</html>"
);
```

so far I have this:

```
$tokens = preg_split("/(\(\w+\(|\)\w+\))/", $code, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
echo json_encode($tokens);
```

but in response I've got this:

```
["\r\n\r\n\r\n","(if(","foo == 10 || (foo == 20 && bar == 30))\r\n ","(foo(","something",")foo)","\r\n",")if)","\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>\r\n"]
```

`<html>` and `<body>` is missing, what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page was html and it `<html>` and `<body>` was interpreted as html so it didn't show up. Setting content-type solved the issue:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```